# how to have image in a class which inherits SKSpritenode

Tags: ios, class, sprite-kit, swift4, skspritenode

I can create an instance of SKSpriteNode class like this

```
let dog = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Dog01")
```

However, how do I do this it if I want to create a custom class which inherits from SKSpriteNode?

E.g.

```
class Dog : SKSpriteNode {



}
```

It looks simple but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do accomplish this:

```
init() {

    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Dog")

    super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clear, size: texture.size())

}
```

I don't know why the above works but some like this does NOT:

```
super.init(imageName: "Dog")
```

Where can I find out from Apple documentation (any other sources) on what is allowed and not allowed? Thanks.

Comment: `SKSpriteNode(imageName: String)` is NOT a proper initializer. It is `SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: String)`

Comment: That what my typing mistake. It should read super.init(imageNamed: "Dog") . Of course Xcode, would point out that it was a mistake. It still does NOT work.

Comment: @MatthewtheCoder, you can check out [this github repo of a cool Spritekit Game](https://github.com/novalain/desert-run). This project might eradicate your confusion. See the Player.swift file and play with your project to implement a SKSpriteNode Subclass

Comment: @MatthewtheCoder, You have a question "I don't know why the above works but some like this does NOT: super.init(imageName: "Dog")"? the answer is SKSpriteNode class has only one designated initializer. If you want to subclass SKSpriteNode class, you must super.init() that particular designated initializer of SKSpriteNode. you should check out this Ray Wenderlich tutorials here: [part 1](https://www.raywenderlich.com/119922/swift-tutorial-initialization-part-1)  [part 2](https://www.raywenderlich.com/121603/swift-tutorial-initialization-part-2)